# Defining an Annotated[str] with constraints in Pydantic v2

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, pydantic

Suppose I want a validator for checksums that I can reuse throughout an application. The Python type-hint system has changed a lot in 3.9+ and that is adding to my confusion. In pydantic v1, I  subclassed `str` and implement `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` and `__get_validators__` class methods. v2 has changed some of this and the preferred way has changed to using annotated types.

In [pydantic-extra-types](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic-extra-types/blob/main/pydantic_extra_types/mac_address.py) package I have found examples that require insight into the inner workings of pydantic. I can copy and get something working, but I would prefer to find the "correct" user's way to do it rather than copying without understanding.

In pydantic v2 it looks like I can make a constrained string as part of a pydantic class, e.g.

```py
from typing import Annotated
from pydantic import BaseModel, StringConstraints

class GeneralThing(BaseModel):
  special_string = Annotated[str, StringConstraints(pattern="^[a-fA-F0-9]{64}$")]
```

but this is not valid (pydantic.errors.PydanticUserError: A non-annotated attribute was detected). Additionally I would have to annotate every field I want to constrain, as opposed to `special_string = ChecksumStr` that I was able to do in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pydantic you need to *annotate* your fields, but you're assigning them.
The following code should do the trick for you

```
from typing import Annotated
from pydantic import BaseModel, StringConstraints

ChecksumString = Annotated[str, StringConstraints(pattern="^[a-fA-F0-9]{64}$")]

class GeneralThing(BaseModel):
  special_string: ChecksumString
```

Note that `special_string: ChecksumString` and not `special_string = ChecksumString`. `special_string: Annotated[str, StringConstraints(...)` would be valid as well just to know.